# jquery - link appended to table doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have some jquery code that adds a row to a table with a link to remove it and return it back to the select. Here's the code:

```
$('#addUser').on('click', function (e) {
    var selectedUser = $('#Utilizadores option:selected').text();
    $('#tabela > tbody:last').append('<tr id="'+selectedUser+'"><td>' + selectedUser + '</td><td><a id="removeUser" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td></tr>');
    $("#Utilizadores option[value='" + selectedUser + "']").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works! But now I want to do the reverse action of this. So I was just tying it out and not even the alert goes off. Here's the remove code:

```
$('#removeUser').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('teste');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The same id I gave to the `<a>` tag but still nothing gets called. I inspect the element and the id is corret and everything.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: try `$(document).on('click','#removeUser', function() {  });`

Comment: Just like @Brian mentioned, you need delegation here. You can't attach an event handler to an element that's not part of the DOM yet.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. If he wants he can make an answer for it so I can approve or something.

Comment: No accepted answer needed, its a duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements) and has been answered well already.

Comment: If you have multiple `id="removeUser"` on the page, I'd suggest changing them to classes `class="removeUser"`. Despite the fact that Event Delegation will work fine with duplicate IDs, it's still bad practice.

Comment: you  need delegated event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles here and doesn't see the warning above!

[You can check a Question for the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the live() method

```
$('#removeUser').live('click', function (e) {
    alert('teste');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: yikes - long since depreciated :)

Comment: touché, its been a while